# Qual è il significato di "rovinare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Il sole si scoperse quando imboccavate lo stradale di San Giovanni, un fiume di polvere pesante che le carrozze, *rovinando*, sollevavano fino al cielo.

Ho cercato il significato di "rovinare" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa significa "rovinando" nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il verbo rovinare può indicare un'azione di movimento, quindi in questo caso indica le carrozze che, procedendo ad "elevata" velocità, sollevavano un certo quantitativo di polvere.

[Qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rovinare/) puoi trovare alcuni esempi come:

> a. Cadere giù crollando, franando, disfacendosi con violenza, riferito a edifici, a strutture e costruzioni edilizie: il palazzo, colpito da una bomba, rovinò con fragore; il pavimento rovinò nella stanza sottostante; il soffitto, il tetto, l’impalcatura, il muro, il ponte minaccia di r.; che rovinare possa questa casa infino ai fondamenti (Sacchetti); riferito a elementi naturali del terreno: durante la mareggiata un gran tratto di costa è rovinato a mare;

Comment: "Quantitivo"? Non trovo questa parola in nessun dizionario.

Comment: @Charo, “quantitativo” esiste (vedi [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quantitativo/), verso la fine), ma fa parte di quel neoitaliano aziendalese che predilige le parole con molte sillabe: “quantitativo” al posto di “quantità”, “tipologia” al posto di “tipo”, “ottimale” al posto di “ottimo”, “metodologia” al posto di “metodo” e molti altri esempi.

Comment: Indica la quantità: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/Q/quantitativo.shtml

Comment: @DaG: Ma allora è "quantitativo" e non "quantitivo", no?

Comment: corretto .. mi era sfuggito :)

Comment: Ah, giusto, @Charo! Non avevo visto che era scritto male.

Answer (score 4):

Qui l'autrice sta estendendo il [significato originario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rovinare/) intransitivo di “rovinare”, che è di “precipitare, venir giù crollando”, per dar l'idea di un moto velocissimo e magari anche rischioso, sulla falsariga di quando si dice “correre a precipizio” e simili, cioè per descrivere una persona o un oggetto che si muove a una velocità tale che sembra stia cadendo.

Un esempio di un uso simile del verbo “rovinare” si trova in un racconto di Tommaso Landolfi (“Mani”, in *Dialogo dei massimi sistemi*). Si parla di un topo che si è nascosto tra le assi di legno della base di un cassone e di una cagna che cerca di afferrarlo:

> Con tutta probabilità il topo, protetto a mezzo dalle sbarre dell'intelaiatura, avendo al sicuro le sue parti più vulnerabili, non combatteva che col terribile grifo. Infine, la situazione divenendogli intollerabile, inganno la cagna con un'abile finta e **rovinò** verso il cortile.

Comment: Molto interessante! Landolfi, come la Banti, usa un linguaggio molto ricercato, a volte quasi ottocentesco.